# Index of an array becomes undefined while looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a small domain availability checker. For that I will parse the desired domain into a form, and submit that to a PHP file with jQuery AJAX.
However while I am looping through the different TLD's it suddenly gets undefined and I am not able to use the "TLD" for further processing within the loop. As far as I can read, it as something to do with the loop happening first and the requests made after, so I somehow have to freeze the index of my array. But I don't know how to do that.

This is my code:

```
$("input[name=submit]").click(function(){
        var getDomain = $("#domainsearch").val();
        var stripDomain = getDomain.split(".");
        var domain = stripDomain[0];
        var tlds = ["dk", "se", "com", "net"];
        for (var i = 0; i < tlds.length; i++ ) {
            var dataString = "domain=" + domain + "." + tlds[i];
            console.log(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(domain + "." + tlds[i] + " is " + data);
                }
            });
        };
        return false;
    });
```

The printed console.log's looks like this:
[image]

Comment: AJAX + loop = need a closure. BRB searching a duplicate.

Comment: You are using the asynchronous method `$.ajax(...)`, meaning that the loop continues to run independently of the ajax request, so the loop finishes, and `i` is no longer defined when you try to reference it for your `success` function. Like @Karl-AndréGagnon said above, you need to use a JS closure to preserve that variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *classic* JavaScript issue.  In the `success` function (a closure), the `i` is being used.  That callback runs in the future, once the AJAX call is done.  By that point, the loop has finished, and `i` has been incremented to `4`.

`tlds[4]` doesn't exist, and that's why you're getting `undefined`.  The callbacks are all using the *same* `i` value.

To fix it, you need to create a new function to capture the value of `i` for each callback.

```
$("input[name=submit]").click(function(){
    var getDomain = $("#domainsearch").val();
    var stripDomain = getDomain.split(".");
    var domain = stripDomain[0];
    var tlds = ["dk", "se", "com", "net"];

    var createCallback = function(i){
        return function(data) {
            console.log(domain + "." + tlds[i] + " is " + data);
        };
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < tlds.length; i++ ) {
        var dataString = "domain=" + domain + "." + tlds[i];
        console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: createCallback(i)
        });
    };
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew I wasn't all wrong. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

By the time the `ajax` calls return, the loop has long since ended, and `i` has run past the end of `tlds`. Trying to print `tlds[i]` is bound to fail.

Break the lookup into a separate function, with local variables that will be valid on the `ajax` callback:

```
var checkup = function(datastring, domain, tld) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(domain + "." + tld + " is " + data);
    }
  });
};

for (var i = 0; i < tlds.length; i++ ) {
  var dataString = "domain=" + domain + "." + tlds[i];
  console.log(dataString);

  checkup(datastring, domain, tlds[i]);
};
```

Comment: This looks even cleaner than my solution, +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the code in your loop in a closure as follows:

```
$("input[name=submit]").click(function(){
    var getDomain = $("#domainsearch").val();
    var stripDomain = getDomain.split(".");
    var domain = stripDomain[0];
    var tlds = ["dk", "se", "com", "net"];
    for (var i = 0; i < tlds.length; i++ ) {
        (function() {
            var dataString = "domain=" + domain + "." + tlds[i];
            console.log(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(domain + "." + tlds[i] + " is " + data);
                }
            });
        })( i );
    }
    return false;
});
```